# Multiple structs that inherit a parent type vs. singular struct with optionals

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to figure out a way to have different types of the same struct and cannot figure out whether to "unify" a singular struct with optionals, or split them up into multiple structs. For example, right now I am making a sports application and have a `Game` struct that differs based on the type of Sport being played: team based (football, basketball) or individual (golf).

The end goal in my application is to pass either struct to a `UITableViewCell` and setup each cell depending on whether it is a team or individual game.

```
struct Game {
    let sportID: String
    let date: Date
    let location: String
    let type: String //Team or Individual
    let teams: [Team]? //Team Game
    let players: [Player]? //Individual Game
}
```

OR

```
struct TeamGame: Game {
    let sportID: String
    let date: Date
    let location: String
    let teams: [Team]
}

struct IndividualGame: Game {
    let sportID: String
    let date: Date
    let location: String
    let players: [Player]
}
```

Is it ultimately based on preference or is there a better/standard manage this?

Comment: A game has two or more participants so maybe Participant should be a protocol or common struct for teams and players.

Comment: Swift structs *cannot* inherit from other structs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Will these structures be used outside of the code you are writing (i.e. if you are developing a library that will be used by several independent consumers)?

If not, don't let [analysis paralysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_paralysis) get you. Pick one way that feels less awkward, and change it later if you feel it doesn't work out. You don't really risk much as long as the code stays in a single app. You can always rewrite it. Besides, it is really hard to give architecture advice without seeing the whole picture.

---

Answering your question directly, the most "natural" way (IMO) will be:

```
enum GameMode {
    case individual(players: [Player])
    case team(teams: [Team])
}

struct Game {
    let sportID: String
    let date: Date
    let location: String
    let mode: GameMode
}
```

---

Edit: more idiomatically, as suggested by @Jessy

```
struct Game {
    enum Mode {
        case individual(players: [Player])
        case team(teams: [Team])
    }
    let sportID: String
    let date: Date
    let location: String
    let mode: Mode
}
```

Comment: @Jessy Because I'm writing too much Rust nowadays, where this is not possible, sadly :-(